# making inner join linq or using [table].[joiningTable].column is the same?

Tags: performance, linq

I have recently started working on linq and I was wondering suppose I have 2 related tables Project (<=with fkAccessLevelId) and AccessLevel and I want to just select values from both tables. Now there are 2 ways I can select values from these tables.

The one i commonly use is:

```
(from P in DataContext.Projects
join AL in DataContext.AccessLevel
on P.AccessLevelId equals AL.AccessLevelId
select new
{
 ProjectName = P.Name,
 Access = AL.AccessName
}
```

Another way of doing this would be:

```
(from P in DataContext.Projects
select new
{
 ProjectName = P.Name,
 Access = P.AccessLevel.AccessName
}
```

What i wanted to know is which of these way is efficient if we increase the number of table say 5-6 with 1-2 tables containing thousands of records...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the SQL generated. You have to understand that there are several main performance bottle necks in a Linq query (in this case I assume a OMG...Linq to SQL?!?!) the usual main bottle neck is the SQL query on the server.

Typically SQL Server has a very good optimizer, so actually, given the same query, refactored, the perf is pretty uniform.

However in your case, there is a very real difference in the two queries. A project with no Access Level would not appear in the first query, whilst the second query would return with a null AccessName. In effect you would be comparing a `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

TL:DR For SQL Server/Linq to Entity Framework queries that do the same thing should give similar performance. However your queries are far from similar.